# Why exporting an unsigned application package in Android?

Tags: android, package, signed

I am wondering why, in Android, there is the possibility to export  unsigned application package ?
As to be able to run in on an Android device, as far as I understand, it must be signed ! !

So what do I do with an unsigned package ?

Cheers.

Comment: have a look on the [Documentation for Signing Your Applications](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html)

Comment: I did read the documentation before posting this.
But from the answers underneath, I understand that the possibility to export an unsigned package is there, so I can sign the application at the next step with a a release key.
I was wondering if it was possible to run an unsigned package: but clearly not from what I knew and the answers I got.

Thanks for answering and clarifying this.

Answer (score 1):

One of the reasons to have that option is so that you can sign that package with any secure key later on.
For example, to publish an app to google play, you need to sign it with a release key(rather than a debug key, which is the default option when you export a signed package from eclipse).

This can be done by exporting a unsigned package and then signing it with a release key.

Answer (score 0):

The question is a little unclear.

Basically, the [app signing process](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html) has the following steps.

1. Create APK
2. Sign and zipalign the APK

Exporting an unsigned package just performs step 1 of above, leaving the remaining to be performed later. An unsigned package cannot be installed. Separating the steps can be useful in some build automation or release process setups. For example, it may not be desirable that every developer has access to release keystore.